# How do I fix unevenly bleached hair that's already been dyed blue

Tags: hair, color

I couldn't find anywhere else on the site to ask this so here goes.  I just got my hair done blue at the salon.  I am thrilled that my hair is now blue, but I am not happy with the quality of the dye job.

Disclaimer, I did get it done at a school so I technically went in knowing it could come out not ideal.  But I have had bad haircuts from expensive places so I have gotten used to rolling the dice a little on the school to save a ton of money.  Often my pixie cuts come out perfectly fine since students are trying so hard to please.  But I do not regularly get my hair colored, so I am new to navigating dye decisions.

Last time I got it dyed there, they didn't bleach enough and/or did not use any ammonia toner, so it came out green and they had to dye it again and it became more cyan.  I actually wanted sky blue but fine whatever.  Soon after a job made me dye it back out.  Years later I finally wanted blue hair again so I went in yesterday.

The student I got unfortunately was not efficient at applying bleach, so the right side of my head was started a long time before the left side.  Then another student came to help and she was amazingly good with the brush... but she worked on my right side.  When they washed out the bleach it looked okay initially.  The teacher also didn't want to use toner like I requested and told them to go straight to dye.  Fine whatever I'm not the expert just finish it.  They put the blue in and I went home.  But now that I am home, I noticed massive blonde and green streaks on my left side.  I tried putting some more blue dye in my hair to saturate better.  The very first spot where bleach was applied is now vibrantly saturated, and the other side is still streaked with green!

Is there anything I can reasonably do to correct this?  Would applying ammonia toner now work?  Should I try to re-bleach a little bit then re-dye?  Or should I give up and accept I have a bad dye job and live with being upset when I look in the mirror?

Comment: I would go back and explain. *Fixing* a botched job is also good training for the students - under the watchful eye of the teacher, of course.

Comment: I feel like they would charge me for a fix because of the whole "You accept it's students" thing when you sign your slip at a school.  Ideally I'd like to not spend a ton seeing as I have already paid $144...

Comment: Asking wouldn’t cost anything?

Comment: True lol!  I'm still open to other answers but I will try asking them.

Comment: if I were you I would never try something stupid cause you may burn it or you may loose its healthy look. Easy and clean way is to cut your hair and let your healthy hair come from deep with its original color. Believe me it is more correct way then reducing your hairs health. Fixing its health back is much much much more hard...

Comment: I am not sure what you're saying, cut all the blue off and regrow my normal hair color?  That's the opposite of my goal lol.  I use keratin treatments to make sure my hair stays strong, it's totally not fried.  Anyways I ended up first using a "blonde" lightener conditioner for a while and that made a huge difference, then I eventually did a re-bleach with purple bleach and re-dyed it to get it the rest of the way there.  It's not perfect but it's totally acceptable now yay!

Answer (score 1):

Anything you do to the colour of your hair now it going to fail keeping the blue in now and may make a mess of what colour is in.

Before a bleach can reach the natural colour in your hair, it will attack the blue which is on the outside. And bleach meant for hair may not be able to take out all the dye put on the outside of your hairs and leave part of the blue, likely in even more uneven patches than you have now.

The only solution to get your hair right is to let it grow out enough to cut it all off.
The second best option is to go to a very good salon and have their best people handle it, with their professional knowledge and supplies.
The third best option, but maybe the best for you, is to go back to the school and lay it in their hands, as they failed. But having done something yourself already makes it less likely they will take it on for free.